# App running in backgroung without UIBackgroundModes property

Tags: objective-c, iphone, geolocation, cllocationmanager

I am fetching location in background using

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
```

I did set the UIBackgroundModes as location in info.plist, but apple rejected it..

Now I tried to run the app without the UIBackgroundModes property and surprisingly the app runs in background (transmitting location) for more then 5hours...

I know apple suspends the app background thread after 10mins.
So is this possible that my app is running without UIBackgroundModes property?   OR I m doing something wrong..

Comment: probably the `info.plist` is still on your device, clean your build (also clean with the alt button pressed). Remove the app from your device and try again.

Comment: your are right rckoenes... I want the app to collect location data in background alltime based on time interval... Apple is rejected app due to UIBackgroundModes as location and suggesting me to use SignificantLocation changes, which I dont want... as I need real time updates and not significant... Can you suggest me any way out..

Comment: What you can do is significant location changes and once you receive a location changes fire up the location manager to get a more specific location. Once you have that stop the location manager and start detecting significant location changes again.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Manmay, we have make sure that Why we are use location service in background mode.

When you are submit application on store.
please include the following battery use disclaimer in your Application Description:

"Continued use of GPS running in the background can dramatically decrease battery life."

When we needed
like example:- in case of location service background needed when we are using "geofencing" functionality that time we have to use location service in background.